# Pandas data.frame, has incorrect indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm pulling data from Yahoo finance, but the data.frame I'm creating won't load because my indices are incorrect.

I know what I need to fix, I just don't know how :/

Here is my code and error:

```
from scipy import stats
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo

ticker = 'IBM'
begdate = (1962,1,1)
enddate = (2013,11,22)

x = quotes_historical_yahoo(ticker, begdate, enddate, asobject = True, adjusted = True)

logret = np.log(x.aclose[1:] / x.aclose[:-1])
date = []
d0 = x.date

print len(logret)

for i in range(0, len(logret)):

    t1 = ''.join([d0[i].strftime("%Y"), d0[i].strftime("%m"), "01"])
    date.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(t1, "%Y%m%d"))
    y = pd.DataFrame(logret, date)
    retM = y.groupby(y.index).sum()

ret_Jan = retM[retM.index.month == 1]
ret_others = retM[retM.index.month != 1]
print sp.stats.bartlett(ret_Jan.values, ret_others.values)
```

The error comes from this line:

```
y = pd.DataFrame(logret, date)
```

And produces this:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 13064), indices imply (1, 1)
```

I believe I need to change logret into a list? ... or a tuple?

But my efforts to convert, using tuple(logret) or creating an empty list and populating it, have not worked so far.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 13064), indices imply (1, 1)
```

means that you've given `pd.DataFrame` a series of length 13064 and an index of length 1, and asked it to index the series by the index. Indeed, that is what you've done: `date` starts off as `[]`, and then you append one value to it, so the index you're passing to the dataframe is just a singleton list.

I think you probably didn't mean to create the DataFrame inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making this a lot harder by going in and out of Pandas objects. If you just stay in Pandas this is pretty simple. I think all you need to do is:

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime 

start = datetime.datetime(1962, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 22) 
f=web.DataReader("IBM", 'yahoo', start, end)
f['returns']    = log(f.Close/f.Close.shift(1)) 

ret_Jan = f.returns[f.index.month == 1]
ret_others = f.returns[f.index.month != 1]

print sp.stats.bartlett(ret_Jan, ret_others)

(122.77708966467267, 1.5602965581388475e-28)
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I had not thought of this solution and I'll try it out :)